# the spectrum of banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let ‎‎$‎A , B ‎‎‎‎‎$ ‎be ‎a‎  ‎banach ‎algebra ‎with ‎identity, and ‎$  ‎\varphi :‎ A ‎‎‎‎\longrightarrow B‎ ‎‎ $  ‎‎is ‎nonzero ‎homoemorphism ‎so ‎that‎ ‎$ ‎\varphi (‎ ‎1‎_{A} ) = 1 ‎‎_{B}‎‎‎‎‎$‎‎
‎

can we say?

> a:‎‎ ‎$ ‎\sigma(‎ ‎\varphi (‎ a‎ ‎))‎ ‎\subseteq‎ ‎\sigma (‎ a‎ )‎ ‎‎ $‎‎
>
> b:‎ ‎$ ‎\varphi (‎ G‎ (‎ ‎A))‎ ‎ ‎\subseteq G (‎ B‎ ‎)) $

$(‎ G‎ ‎(A) =‎ ‎\{ a‎ ‎\in A‎ :  \textrm{a ‎‎‎‎is ‎‎invertible} ‎\} ‎)‎ $‎

Answer (score 0):

We can certainly state that b holds.  In particular: if $a \in A$ has inverse $a^{-1}$, then $\varphi(a)\varphi(a^{-1}) = \varphi(a^{-1}) \varphi(a) = 1_B$, which means that $\varphi(a) \in G(B)$.

Spectrum is a little trickier.  We have
$$
\lambda \notin \sigma(a) \implies\\
(a - \lambda I) \in G(A) \implies\\
\varphi(a - \lambda I) \in G(B) \implies\\
\varphi(a) - \lambda I \in G(B) \implies\\
\lambda \notin \sigma(\varphi(a))
$$
Thus, by contrapositive, we have $\lambda \in \sigma(\varphi(a)) \implies \lambda \in \sigma(a)$.  That is, $\sigma(\varphi(a)) \subseteq \sigma(a)$, as was desired.

Comment: To get an equality for part a , is the onto condition for homomorphism is enough ?